# Why does the signature of deriveHCons declare `HK <: Symbol` when Symbol is a final class

Tags: scala, generics, subclassing, generic-programming, shapeless

Here is the signature of `deriveHCons` in `LabelledProductTypeClassCompanion` of Shapeless:

```
implicit def deriveHCons[HK <: Symbol, HV, TKV <: HList]
    (implicit
      ch: Lazy[C[HV]],
      key: Witness.Aux[HK],
      ct: Lazy[Wrap[TKV] { type V <: HList }]
    ): Wrap.Aux[FieldType[HK, HV] :: TKV, HV :: ct.value.V] = ...
```

It seems strange to me that we declare a type parameter `HK` that must derive from `Symbol` when `Symbol` is a final class. How can anything but `Symbol` replace the type parameter `HK`? If `HK` is always `Symbol`, this signature would be less imposing if it got rid of HK and substituted Symbol in the type signature directly would it not?

Comment: Well... you know what is the purpose of `Shapeless`...  type based generic programming enabling things which are normally not possible with Scala.-- https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#singleton-typed-symbols

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Thx for the pointer! Still not sure I understand exactly how all this is working, but I have a starting point for acquiring a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to explain why this applies for `Int`, but it's actually the same for `Symbol`.

`Int` is final right? Here is an instance of it:

```
val n = 2
```

But we can actually give `n` a more precise type than that. How? With  [literal singleton types](https://speakerdeck.com/folone/42-dot-type-literal-based-singleton-types):

```
val n: Witness.`2`.T = 2
```

Now `n` has type `` Witness.`2`.T ``, a.k.a. `2.type`, or just *type* `2`. `2` is the sole inhabitant of it, e.g. `` 3: Witness.`2`.T `` will not compile. And we have `` Witness.`2`.T <: Int ``

The same thing applies to symbols: although `Symbol` is final, its values, the literal ones in particular, can be given more refined types, the ones that correspond to these values:

```
val s = Symbol("s")
val refined: Witness.`'s`.T = Symbol("s")
```

Comment: The code snippets require importing `syntax.singleton._
` to compile.